# does getlastknownlocation run in a separate thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, location, progressdialog

I had this simple doubt.
I have to display a progress dialog when the phone is getting location update.

 
Do I need to do this in a separate thread or does getLastKnownLocation already run in a separate thread. 
If it doesnt can anyone please post a small sample code, the most effective way to do this? 
I went through the android api source and did not succeed in finding out the working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getLastKnownLocation` runs synchronously and it doesn't actually get the current location (which is what you probably want). Here is the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29

The highlights:

> Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location
>   fix obtained from the given provider. This can be done without
>   starting the provider. Note that this location could be out-of-date,
>   for example if the device was turned off and moved to another
>   location.
>
> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

What you probably want is something more along the lines of this question: [displaying progress dialog at the start of a gps application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958695/displaying-progress-dialog-at-the-start-of-a-gps-application)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However the link you suggested requests location updates every 10 seconds. I just want one update on the location. That is why I am using getLastKnownLocation. Is there a better way to do this? It is imperative that I do not use much of user's battery by requesting location updates more than required.

Comment: @Brahadeesh you can also [requestSingleUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Comment: does requestSingleUpdate run synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: @Brahadees, it's asynchronous, but if you specify a listener, then you will get a callback when the location is available: `public void requestSingleUpdate (Criteria criteria, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)` [See the documentation of requestSingleUpdate for more details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper%29)